# I'm using cloud-functions-emulator, 1 Param is OK, but 2 Param?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use cloud-functions-emulator, When I try to call with 1 Parameter,
like 
functions call auth --data {\"token\":\"1234ssss\"}

everythings fine, but When I try to call with 2 Param,

like

functions call auth --functions call hell --data '{\"names\":\"test.txt\",\"buket\":\"my-bucketssssssss\"}'

is making an error  = Error: "data" must be a valid JSON string!

how can I go with 2 Params??

Answer (score 0):

Try the following two commands:

```
echo "{\"hello\": \"world\"}"
```

and

```
echo '{\"hello\": \"world\"}'
```

The outputs will be:

```
{"hello": "world"}
```

and

```
{\"hello\": \"world\"}
```

Notice that supplying your command in single quotes cancels the escaping of the double quotes resulting in un-desired content.  Try your command as:

```
functions call auth --functions call hell --data "{\"names\":\"test.txt\",\"buket\":\"my-bucketssssssss\"}"
```

or

```
functions call auth --functions call hell --data '{"names":"test.txt","buket":"my-bucketssssssss"}'
```